# removing backbone events for unused class (events are triggered twice)

Tags: events, backbone.js

I have two backbone view classes fileView and userDetails.

On one page of the web app I use the fileView to render all files

On another page I use the userDetails view to display the user details and also create a new instance of the fileView to also list the user files.

After I navigate on both pages my events are triggered twice (once for filesView and once for userDetails.fileView).

How can I remove events for userDetails.fileView? I read the documentation and tried anything so far with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, the answer is here.

[Derick Bailey: Managing event removal](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/)

I use this approack in all my backbone apps, but full credit must go to Derick Bailey :)

Thanks Derick!

Answer (score 1):

I think you got two points to achieve this:

1. For events in backbone DON'T use object.on(event, callback, context)
   as possible as you can. Because it will pass the object's reference
   to the callback and you hardly have chance to remove it. instead,
   use object.listenTo(other, event, callback), so you can user
   object.stopListening() to remove them.
2. with the above in mind you can create a helper function in your
   view, say "dispose". In that function, first you stopListening() all
   events attach to your view, then remove() it from DOM tree.

here's some intel in more detail:
http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#memory-management

Comment: Actually removing a view calling its `remove()` function will also stop listening to any event monitored via `listenTo()`, so there's no need for a `dispose` function in this specific case. Relevant code in Backbone.js http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-128

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle events with recent versions of Backbone is the [`listenTo()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) function. It behaves like a regular event listener but makes the object you call this function on aware of what they are listening to. This way, you can get automatic cleanup once the object is not used anymore (for instance when a View is removed). You can of course call [`stopListening()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) to manually trigger this behaviour if needed.